# Removing Pivot items causes an exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application, I basically remove Pivot Items after the asynchronous method. But it throws an Argument Out Of Range exception and says Value does not fall with in the expected range. But in case , if i do this removal before to the invoking of asynchronous method everything getting succeeds. Please check my below code. I am not able to exactly trigger out the main problem arises in the code. Could you please anyone help me on this ?

```
var a=await GetA();
if(a.Value)
{
   if(myPivot.Items.Contains(pivItem))
   {
      myPivot.Items.Remove(pivItem);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code! Preferably small snippet that reproduces you problem and exact error that you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by narrow down the issue, I found out that if I remove the `PivotItem.Header` element, there will be no more exceptions.